# Fuzzy Cellular Automata in matlab

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic, cellular-automata

I need to know how to create a fuzzy Cellular Automata in matlab for image Processing and I am beginner.Should i write  the code or i could use fuzzy logic toolbar in matlab ?Could anyone introduce some source for fuzzy Cellular Automata to me? I search in mathworks but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to find a Fuzzy Cellular Automata toolbox for Matlab, but fuzzy toolbox, as you noted, is available. And... RBN toolbox, which is used for simulating cellular automata in Matlab, can be integrated with the fuzzy toolbox to get fuzzy CA (depending upon your implementation).

(If you're not already aware of RBN toolbox, try this: http://www.teuscher-research.com/rbntoolbox/UsingToolbox/CA_application.htm)

However, given that you're using the CA for image processing, I'd strongly suggest using C/C++/Java/Perl to get this done. I have used Java and Perl for CA and it is a breeze. Implementing the fuzzy logic should require a little more effort, but this should be pretty doable.

However, I do not think there is any ready-to-use fuzzy CA plugin for Matlab.

P.S: Although I haven't tried/checked this out in details, this link might help you:  http://en.pudn.com/downloads292/sourcecode/math/detail1313119_en.html